# How I can Update args value in scipy.optimize.minimize function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, argument-passing, minimize

In my problem, I need to update the args value inside the cost function, but the args is a function argument and also has the tuple structure. I was wondering is there a way to change the element of args and update it to use it by jac function? For example, in the below codes

```
paraList = [detValVec, projTrans, MeasVec, 
            coeMat, resVec, absCoeRec]
res = optimize.minimize(costFunc, x0, args=(paraList,), method='BFGS', jac=gradientFunc, options={'gtol': 1e-6, 'disp': True}) 
def costFunc(x0,arg):
    para = list(arg)
    para[3], para[4], para[5] = forwardModelFunc(para[0], para[1], para[2]) 
    return para[5]
```

I would like to update para[3], para[4], para[5] in the args argument.

Comment: Your `costFunc` does not depend on `x0`. It cannot be minimized with respect to `x0` if changing `x0` has no effect? You need to rearrange your function so that the "parameter" you want to change is the first (`x0`) argument.

Answer (score 1):

In order to minimize `costFunc` you must be able to vary the input parameters (otherwise it'll always have the same value!). The `optimize.minimize` function will vary ("update") the `x` but it will leave `args` untouched as it calls `costFunc`, which means that your `paraList` should really be given as `x`, not `args`.

Since `costFunc` depends only on the first three values in your parameter list `para[:3]`,  updating the last three `para[3:]` will have no effect, so you can use `x = para[:3]` and `args = para[3:]`. In fact, you don't even need `args` at all, since it has no effect.

Something like:

```
paraList = [detValVec, projTrans, MeasVec, coeMat, resVec, absCoeRec]

def costFunc(x):
    out = forwardModelFunc(x[0], x[1], x[2]) 
    return out[2]

x0 = paraList[:3] # the initial guess
res = optimize.minimize(costFunc, x0, method='BFGS', jac=gradientFunc,
                        options={'gtol': 1e-6, 'disp': True})
```

So the optimal result you'll get (returned in `res.x`) will be the best values for the first three parameters in `paraList`: `detValVec`, `projTrans`, and `MeasVec`. If you want to get the last three values that they imply, you can just call `forwardModelFunc` on `res.x`:

```
paraList_opt = list(res.x) + list(forwardModelFunc(*res.x)
```

Of course, it's important to understand the limitations of `optimize.minimize`: it can only minimize over an array `x` if it is a 1d array of scalars, so hopefully the values in your `paramList` are scalars. If not, you'll have to flatten and concatenate them. Also, it will pass the same `x` and `args` to the jacobian `gradientFunc`, so be sure that it is properly formatted as well.